# creating simple command for sudo apt-get install?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, alias, function

I need to run these commands very often:

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

Can I make it simple like:

```
install <package>
remove  <package>
```

I think I need to write a function like this:

```
function install(){
sudo apt-get install <package>
}
```

...and then need to copy paste to some location i don't know. Can anyone tell me how can I make such an `install <package>` command available all the time after boot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use shell aliases, they won't interfere with other scripts/commands, they are only replaced when the command has been typed interactively:

```
alias install="sudo apt-get install"
```

You may place this in your shell configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for example) and it will be defined in all your shell sessions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$1` (and so on for Nth) to refer to the first argument passed to a function or `$*` to refer to all of them. The `$@` format refers to all the arguments passed but will expand into separate words:

```
function install(){
    sudo apt-get install "$@"
}
```

You could then put this in your `~/.bashrc` file so that it will be available every time you login.

In this case, a simple alias might also do the trick:

```
$ alias install="sudo apt-get install"
```

That can also be placed in the same file.

Comment: alias will be temporary ?

Comment: @mr_eclair: As I mentioned, you can place aliases in `~/.bashrc` in the same way so that you have them every time you pull up a bash shell.